# Multiple Release Environment with Xcode 9 - Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, duplicates, target

I have finished writing a project and released to AppStore. Now i want to duplicate the project and change Bundle ID, Signing certificates, Splash Screen, the project specific links and images used in Storyboard.

Since the Model classes and business model wont change at all. And instead of copy-paste the project, change on classes and when bug comes up fixing it on both projects, changes will be only on interface and signing stuff on the same project.

Is that possible?

Is there anyway that this can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create copy of your target, which will allow you to create a separate app with same project business (code) logic and different Bundle ID, Signing certificates, Splash Screen, the project specific links.

Here are steps to create duplicate target:

1. Select Your Project Target (Project >> General >> Select Target)
2. Right Click on Project Target
3. Select `Duplicate` (Menu popover will provide your option to create a duplicate target)

[image]

4. Here is duplicate copy of your target, that you can distribute as a New app with same business logic.

[image]

Your future updates/changes in code will effect on both target, if your source code file has assigned both targets.

Note: Just make sure, when ever you create a new file (after creating duplicate/multiple target), assign.select both targets to make it effective for both apps.

[image]

Look at here, my new file `TestFile.swift` has (links to) multiple targets.

[image]

Now to identify your project target programmatically and differentiate your links:

```
var API_LINK = ""

if let targetName = NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary?["CFBundleName"] as? String {

    if (targetName == "Test") {

        API_LINK = "http://webservice.Test"

    } else if (targetName == "Test copy") {

        API_LINK = "http://webservice.TestCopy"

    } else {

        print("Something wrong - targetName not found")

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you :) looks easy ! but i have questions still, This way, How to specify the links and Storyboard images ?

Comment: Great explanation, what i did not get is this, I have `Constants.swift` file, It contains `API_LINK = "http://webservice.link";`, inside `Constants.swift` file, how can we recognize which target is it ? and which api link is needed ?

Comment: Using target name constant, you need to set if-else condition. Create a target name constant (strings or enum) and check it during run time

Comment: `picture worth a thousand words` :) Thank you for the neat answer